# How to Change the Background of Border when ComboBox get the Focus

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a Border which Content ComboBox, Now i want to change the Backround of the Border when the ComboBox get the Focus!!!

I have tried this code but it's not work :(

```
<Border CornerRadius="4" Margin="6,2,2,2" >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="Tester">   
        <Label Content=" Signature :" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="14"  ToolTip="You can join a file text containing your query with simple drag and drop of file here"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="Signatures" Margin="2,4,4,4" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" FontWeight="Normal" FontFamily="Times New Roman" Width="180" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" IsEditable="True" FontSize="14" MouseDoubleClick="Signatures_MouseDoubleClick" MouseLeftButtonDown="Signatures_MouseDoubleClick"  >
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Serializable" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Normal" />
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Comparable" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="CharSequence" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Number" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="String" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="long" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="short" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="integer" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="double" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="float" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="byte" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="boolean" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="void" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Signatures, Path=IsFocused}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="BurlyWood"/>
                </DataTrigger>

            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
</Border>
```

Can you help me please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the focus is not exactly on your `ComboBox` but on a sub-element and AFAIK WPF is not able to tell you if the focus is within an element.

So you should add more `DataTrigger`s:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Signatures,Path=IsFocused}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="BurlyWood"/>
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Signatures,Path=IsSelectionBoxHighlighted}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="BurlyWood"/>
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Signatures,Path=IsDropDownOpen}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="BurlyWood"/>
    </DataTrigger>
```